# list of object is updating its values on updating another object in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

When I am updating my Some properties of my MstService Class Object, on the same time it is updating SList of type List Too,Don't know why??[image]

```
protected MstService Service { get; set; } = new MstService();
        public List<MstService> SList { get; set; } = new List<MstService>();        

        public async Task ResetForm()
        {
            Service.Id = 0;
            Service.Name = "";
            Service.IsActive = false;
            values.Clear();
            btnSubmitDisabled = false;
            btnAddRangeDisabled = false;
            btnRemoveDisabled = false;
            SList = (await serviceMater.GetServices()).ToList();
        }
```

Why the values are changing in SList [image]

[image]

Comment: can you show us the definition of `GetServices`? are you adding `Service` to `SList ` list somewhere in your code?

Comment: public async Task<IEnumerable<MstService>> GetServices()
        {
            return await _context.MstServices.ToListAsync();
        }

Comment: And I am not adding Service to SList  list Anywhere in my code.